# How to log each user input tried in Http Basic Authentication Prompt

Tags: php, http-headers, basic-authentication

I want to be able to keep a log of all the various combination of username and password tried. whether it is the correct combination or not. Is this possible?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: thanks for the comment. going through the link you suggested